# Perform OS X swipes on PC mouse and keyboard

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, mouse

Is there a way to perform OS X's swipe gestures using Windows-style mouse and keyboard?

In this case OS X 10.7 runs as a guest inside a virtualization environment. To OS X it appears as if a standard PC keyboard and two-button mouse are attached over USB. These two are the only input devices present.

**Edit:** I don't mean to perform the same finger movements, like swiping 3 fingers over a trackpad. My question is whether there is a list of standardized keyboard shortcuts, or combinations of keyboard and mouse actions, which quickly does the same as swipes.

Comment: What are you using exactly to virtualize OS X 10.7 ?

Comment: @Antoine: I'm not quite sure whether it helps you to answer my question or not; but the virtualization layer is a VMWare Player 4.

Comment: Unless you have a touchpad with multi-touch support, it won't be possible to emulate it. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

By default:

Move Right One Page: `[swipe left]` or `ctrl` +`[rightarrow]`
Move Left One Page: `[swipe right]` or `ctrl` + `[leftarrow]`
Mission Control: `[swipe up]` or `ctrl` + `[uparrow]`
App Expose: `[swipe down]` or `ctrl` + `[downarrow]`

You can change these shortcuts in System Preferences.app -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are standard keyboard shortcuts and standard gestures, but you can customize them; in fact, you can turn off gestures completely if you have no practical way to use them. Look in System Preferences for the Keyboard and Trackpad settings.

Answer (score 0):

I made [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org).

It lets you use Mission Control, App Exposé, and Switch between Spaces by simply clicking and dragging in different directions. It also feels super responsive and native.

On top of that it's open source, easy to use, 100% free, and it also has a bunch of other cool features that make your mouse better!

[Download](https://mousefix.org) | [GitHub](https://github.com/noah-nuebling/mac-mouse-fix)